# Data Flow between VLANS

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-asa, firewall, packet-path

I have a setup like this. (Yes, I suck at Paint)

[image]

What I know is:

1) Only the ASA knows sees PCA **AND** PCB. Because the ASA is the only one who is connected to both VLANS. Am I right?

If I want to Download a File from PCB to PCA. Does the file (10GB big), uses Route1 (the blue one) for the whole 10GB file?
OR does the ASA say to the PC something like "`Hey the PC is connected to PORT1, you don't have to send the whole package over cable1 and cable2!`" and then the File never leaves the Switch and goes over Route2 (the black one)?

I want to know this, because our Server and Clients are on different VLANS. If the file never leaves the Switch, I will put the Clients with the Server they need most often on the some switch.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, *there is no `route 2`*. VLANs 10 and 20 could just as easily be two physical switches. Also, the ASA doesn't know anything about the topology (i.e. PCA is on port 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosts on one VLAN cannot communicate with hosts on another VLAN, except through a layer-3 device, e.g. a router.

A VLAN is a layer-2 concept. When hosts communicate, they use layer-2 to communicate on the LAN. VLANs prevent this from happening by dividing the LAN into virtual LANs. A host needing the layer-2 (e.g. MAC) address of the destination will broadcast an ARP request for the destination host's address. A broadcast will only be sent in the LAN or VLAN (broadcast domain). It the destination is on another network, the sending host will use its configured gateway's layer-2 address as the destination layer-2 address.

In your specific case, the switch will keep the traffic in each VLAN separate, and it will only send it directly from one host port to the other if it is a layer-3 switch with routing enabled between the VLANs, and it is configured in the hosts' as the gateway. Otherwise, if the only routing is happening on the ASA, the traffic will need to travel through the ASA.

Comment: Also note that an ASA can be configured either to route traffic between VLANs (interfaces) with the same security level, or to **not** route traffic (by default) between interfaces with the same security level. In this case that means it's not a given that the ASA will allow traffic between PCA and PCB simply because they are both connected to the ASA.

Comment: Thanks. @ToddWilcox yeah I know, they will be on the same security level ;-) and i will configure it, that the two vlans are routed.
ATRon: Shit, thats not what i hoped. In conclusion, if I use a L2 Switch (SG500X, Catalyst 2960X etc.) the bandwidth of cable 1 &2 will be affacted for other user?

Comment: @SystemCookie Yes, if you don't have a layer 3 switch or router-on-a-stick available, and you use the ASA for inter-VLAN routing, then all of your inter-VLAN traffic will share with your Internet and VPN traffic. The upside of inter-VLAN traffic on the ASA is you can leverage ASA rules to block and allow traffic between VLANs based on different criteria. If there are no inter-VLAN security concerns, a layer 3 switch or router-on-a-stick would be more ideal.

Comment: @SystemCookie, when you say that the bandwidth of one cable will be affected by the other user, you are probably running full duplex, so understand that the bandwidth for incoming and outgoing traffic on the same cable are separate, and one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. So maybe I will get a L3 Switch for the important File Servers where the most traffic is taking place. Any good L3 switches by cisco? After seeing the price, L2 will do it ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Doesn't matter - see edit ;-) Thanks!

Comment: If I would make Port A, Port 1 and Port 2 a trunk Port with VLAN10, VLAN20 and remove the Cable from B to 8. Would then route2 work?

Comment: To get from one IP network to another, a host will send, at layer-2, the traffic to its configured gateway. The traffic must travel through a router, even if the router is in a firewall or a layer-3 switch. You simply cannot send traffic from one VLAN to another without a layer-3 device in between the VLANs. That is the whole point of using VLANs.